# Is it possible to create copy of Map Iterators in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

```
public boolean placeLizardsByDFS(int noOfQueens){
        if(noOfQueens == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Iterator itForRow  = allowedRows.entrySet().iterator();
            while (itForRow.hasNext()) {
                double tempRow = (Double) ((Map.Entry) itForRow.next()).getKey();
                Iterator itForColumn = allowedColumns.entrySet().iterator();
                while(itForColumn.hasNext()) {
                    double tempColumn = (Double) ((Map.Entry) itForColumn.next()).getKey();
                    placeQueen(tempRow, tempColumn);
                    if (placeLizardsByDFS(noOfQueens - 1))
                        return true;
                    else
                        removeQueen(tempRow, tempColumn, tempRangeForRow, tempRangeForColumn);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to solve the N queens problem. But seems like with bigger inputs, my code is inefficient. I'm trying to optimize by reducing the no. of rows and columns to search for deeper levels of recursion. So is it possible to pass a copy of iterator for the map? 
 The problem I'm facing here is whether I can pass a new iterator for the next level of recursion without the iterator at the higher level getting affected since Java is call by reference?

Comment: Why using a Map with Double as the key (which basically is the index)?  Just a 2D array (or List-of-List) should already be good enough.  "passing iterator" in such case is just passing the current position.

Comment: I'm using a map coz I need quick checks for whether element exists in the collection. The problem I'm facing here is whether I can pass a new iterator for the next level of recursion without the iterator at the higher level getting affected since Java is call by reference?

Comment: it won't be quicker than using a 2D array. No you won't be able create a copy of iterator (You may try `iterator.clone()`, it may work but it will not be reliable).  To solve the inefficiency, fix your design first